# XAMPP phpmyadmin : Login credentials

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm having a problem logging in to my phpmyadmin.

Initially, I had **xampplite** in my PC and it runs on **PHP 5.3.1**.

Then I installed another **xampp** version which has **PHP 5.5.x** because I wanted to test a site.

Now, after using the newly installed **xampp**, I uninstalled it and removed from my C:.

I started the control panel of **xampplite** but when I access **phpmyadmin**, it asks for the login credentials.

I entered what I remembered but I can't login because

> "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)"

I'm sure that the password is just blank but how come I can't login anymore?

I checked  **config.inc.php** file but there is no password set there.

I already tried changing the `auth_type` from `cookie` to `http` to `config` but none is working.

I need to retrieve this since I have an important database stored in my **xampplite** **phpmyadmin**.

Help will really be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you uninstall xamp from control panel?

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

If all the changes you made are in your post, I think you forgot to change the `AllowNoPassword` to **TRUE**. I'm going to explain the steps to activate/desactivate password on phpMyAdmin DBMS

First of all you need to have acces to your **Xampp Control Panel** or to the **Xampp Root Directory**, you can do it by directly console file edition
or with Xampp Visual Interface:

1. Go to the Xampp Control Panel and open config/phpMyAdmin
   (config.inc.php)

   ```sh
   sudo nano path/to/xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
   ```

   or

   ```sh
   sudo vim path/to/xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
   ```

   Identify the **Auth Type** and **Allow No Password Array** Take the code layout below as an example:

   ```
   /* Authentication type and info */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
   $cfg['Lang'] = '';
   ```
2. Change the **auth_type** and **AllowNoPassword** to 'cookie'(string)
   and false(bool) as shown below:

   ```
   /* Authentication type and info */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
   $cfg['Lang'] = '';
   * Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';  
   ?>
   ```
3. Restart your server

Hope it helped you

*Images and reference:*

[Step 1: Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V336.png)

[Step 2: Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNm06.png)

[Ref: Here you can check more info](https://goocoder.com/enable-login-phpmyadmin-on-xampp/)